# Partially join two dataframes/tibbles

Tags: r, join, tidyverse

I have two data-frames/tibbles. The first one is a list of countries with several variables describing these countries. This data-frame contains several missing values. Which variables are missing depends on the country.

```
library(tidyverse)

df1<-data.frame(id=1:10, 
                country=c("A","A","A","A","B","B","C","C","C","C"), 
                var1=c(NA,NA,NA,NA,1,1,2,1,2,1), 
                var2=c(1,1,2,2,NA,NA,1,2,2,2),
                var3=c("NO","YES","NO","YES","NO","NO",NA,NA,NA,NA),
                var4=c(NA,NA,NA,NA,"NO","NO",NA,NA,NA,NA)
               )
df1<-as_tibble(df1)
```

Then I have a second data-frame (df2) I would like to join with the first table:

```
df2<-data.frame(id=c(2,3,5,6,7,8,9,10),
                country=c("A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C", "C"),
                var1=c(1,2,2,2,2,1,2,1),
                var2=c(2,1,1,1,1,2,1,1),
                var3=c("NO","NO", "YES", "NO", "NO", "NO", "YES","NO"),
                var4=c("YES", "NO", "NO", "YES", "YES", "NO", "NO", "YES")
               )
df2<-as_tibble(df2)
```

Finally, what I'd like to have is the first data-frame where the missing values are completed using the second data-frame. So I'd like to join both tables using the `id`-Variable. However, this join should only be "partly", because which variables are missing depends on the country: e.g. for country "A" only the variables `var1` and `var4` should be filled in. In country "C" the variables `var3` and `var4` should be filled in from df2. df1 contains more cases than df2.

Can anyone please tell me which is the best solution in order to solve that problem?

Thank you very much!

Comment: I suggest you rename the "var" variables in `df2`, do a `merge` (or `dplyr::left_join`), then a conditional assignment into the original variables of `df1`. Do you have any code yet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one potential solution for the provided data. I added `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` to both data frames. Seeing the data, I thought you would want to bind them rather than joining them. Once I bound the data, I sorted it by `id`, `country`, and `index`. `index` indicates from which data frame data came. Then, I created groups by `id` and `country`. For groups that have two rows, first row has the target NAs that you want to fill in. These NAs stay in four columns (i.e., `var1-4`). I applied `na.locf()` in the `zoo` package to do the filling process. For each group the first row is from `df1` and you want to keep them. I chose to use `distinct()` here. But `slice(1)` is another option.

```
df1 <- data.frame(id=1:10, 
                  country=c("A","A","A","A","B","B","C","C","C","C"), 
                  var1=c(NA,NA,NA,NA,1,1,2,1,2,1), 
                  var2=c(1,1,2,2,NA,NA,1,2,2,2),
                  var3=c("NO","YES","NO","YES","NO","NO",NA,NA,NA,NA),
                  var4=c(NA,NA,NA,NA,"NO","NO",NA,NA,NA,NA),
                  stringsAsFactors = F)

 df2 <- data.frame(id=c(2,3,5,6,7,8,9,10),
                   country=c("A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C", "C"),
                   var1=c(1,2,2,2,2,1,2,1),
                   var2=c(2,1,1,1,1,2,1,1),
                   var3=c("NO","NO", "YES", "NO", "NO", "NO", "YES","NO"),
                   var4=c("YES", "NO", "NO", "YES", "YES", "NO", "NO", "YES"),
                  stringsAsFactors = F)

 library(dplyr)
 library(zoo)

bind_rows(df1, df2, .id = "index") %>%
arrange(id, country, index) %>%
group_by(id, country) %>%
mutate_at(vars(var1:var4), funs(if(n() > 1) {na.locf(., fromLast = TRUE)} else {.})) %>%
distinct(id, .keep_all = TRUE) %>%
select(-index)



      id country  var1  var2 var3  var4 
   <dbl> <chr>   <dbl> <dbl> <chr> <chr>
 1  1.00 A       NA     1.00 NO    <NA> 
 2  2.00 A        1.00  1.00 YES   YES  
 3  3.00 A        2.00  2.00 NO    NO   
 4  4.00 A       NA     2.00 YES   <NA> 
 5  5.00 B        1.00  1.00 NO    NO   
 6  6.00 B        1.00  1.00 NO    NO   
 7  7.00 C        2.00  1.00 NO    YES  
 8  8.00 C        1.00  2.00 NO    NO   
 9  9.00 C        2.00  2.00 YES   NO   
10 10.0  C        1.00  2.00 NO    YES
```

Answer (score 1):

---

Updated suggestion that preserves type but requires a little literal code.

```
rename_at(df2, vars(starts_with("var")), ~ paste0("new", .)) %>%
  select(-country) %>%
  right_join(df1, by = "id") %>%
  mutate(
    var1 = if_else(is.na(var1), newvar1, var1),
    var2 = if_else(is.na(var2), newvar2, var2),
    var3 = if_else(is.na(var3), newvar3, var3),
    var4 = if_else(is.na(var4), newvar4, var4)
  ) %>%
  select(-starts_with("newvar"))
```

An alternative to using is to loop (externally to the pipe) over relevant column names:

```
df3 <- rename_at(df2, vars(starts_with("var")), ~ paste0("new", .)) %>%
  select(-country) %>%
  right_join(df1, by = "id")
for (v in colnames(df1)[ grepl("^var", colnames(df1)) ]) {
  df3[[v]] <- if_else(is.na(df3[[v]]), df3[[ paste0("new", v) ]], df3[[v]])
}
select(df3, -starts_with("newvar"))
```

---

**Edit**: oops, just realized that "var" columns are mixed-type. The below answer works if all are the same, but not here. Use of the previous code preserves type.

If you rename the "var" variables in `df2`, you can do a side-by-side comparison and reassignment of `df1`'s "var" variables. One approach might be to use `dplyr::mutate_if` and `starts_with("var")`, but that imposes a possibly-too-strict requirement on your data.

I suggest using an intermediate "tall" (versus "wide") format to make dealing with `var1` through `var4` generalized; that way, if you actually have more, you don't need to iterate through each variable.

Assumption: `df2$id` should suffice, `id$country` is unnecessary.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df1<-data_frame(id=1:10, 
                country=c("A","A","A","A","B","B","C","C","C","C"), 
                var1=c(NA,NA,NA,NA,1,1,2,1,2,1), 
                var2=c(1,1,2,2,NA,NA,1,2,2,2),
                var3=c("NO","YES","NO","YES","NO","NO",NA,NA,NA,NA),
                var4=c(NA,NA,NA,NA,"NO","NO",NA,NA,NA,NA)
               )

df2<-data_frame(id=c(2,3,5,6,7,8,9,10),
                country=c("A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C", "C"),
                var1=c(1,2,2,2,2,1,2,1),
                var2=c(2,1,1,1,1,2,1,1),
                var3=c("NO","NO", "YES", "NO", "NO", "NO", "YES","NO"),
                var4=c("YES", "NO", "NO", "YES", "YES", "NO", "NO", "YES")
                )

select(df2, -country) %>%
  gather(k, newv, -id) %>%
  right_join(gather(df1, k, v, -id, -country), by = c("id", "k")) %>%
  mutate(v = ifelse(is.na(v), newv, v)) %>%
  select(-newv) %>%
  spread(k, v)
# # A tibble: 10 × 6
#       id country  var1  var2  var3  var4
# *  <dbl>   <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
# 1      1       A  <NA>     1    NO  <NA>
# 2      2       A     1     1   YES   YES
# 3      3       A     2     2    NO    NO
# 4      4       A  <NA>     2   YES  <NA>
# 5      5       B     1     1    NO    NO
# 6      6       B     1     1    NO    NO
# 7      7       C     2     1    NO   YES
# 8      8       C     1     2    NO    NO
# 9      9       C     2     2   YES    NO
# 10    10       C     1     2    NO   YES
```